# nginx rewrite rules for app api

Tags: nginx

I have a question regarding nginx rewrite/redirect rules.

I have an app that is running on `app.example.com`, and I want to forward all requests that hits this server to another subdomain: `api.example.com`

I have all api-related stuff in this folder: `/react-api`

I have managed to get this working:

```
location ~ /react-api {
    rewrite ^(.+)$ http://api.example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

It works perfectly in the browser, but when I try to run it in my app, it doesn't work. I think it has something to do with the fact that it is a `301 redirect` right? And the app can't work with that?

How do I solve this problem?

Appreciate all help!

**UPDATE**
I've tried `proxy_pass`

```
location /react-api/(.*) {
    proxy_pass http://api.example.com/$is_args$args/;
}
```

But I couldn't get that working either.

Comment: Why is this question tagged `.htaccess`?

Comment: Make your app to handle redirects, or better make your app to request api.example.com

Comment: @arkascha that was a mistake :)

Comment: @AlexeyTen yes I know, but how can I do it now that the app is already live? I need some way to redirect the requests without making changes to the app

Comment: Then you need proxy_pass

Comment: @AlexeyTen see updated question

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use upstreams and proxy_pass as a solution

Set api.example.com as a upstream.

```
upsteram api-server {
    server api.example.com;
}
```

Configure the API locationto use the new upstream.

```
location ~ /react-api/(.*) {
    proxy_pass api-server/$is_args$args
}
```

There are a little bit more than this to be configured in order to get a API proxy working correctly (such headers forwarding).
For more information about nginx variables and upstrems read these documents:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

Answer (score 0):

You just need simple proxy pass.

```
location /rest-api/ {
    proxy_pass http://api.example.com/rest-api/;
}
```

That's it.
No need to add query arguments, they are copied by default.